# HTML window.scroll method only works correctly on localhost

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I have tried calling parent.scroll & parent.window.scroll to scroll the browser window from a child frame. However,

Localhost testing: Works in IE, Firefox, & Chrome.
Production/Non-localhost: Works only in Chrome.

Can you guys tell me why this might be the case?

Comment: You really should post the actual code you're using.

Comment: The iframe and parent window don't have same protocol and domain then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might just want to use window.scroll(X, Y), or maybe window.scrollBy(X, Y). In both cases omitting "parent"

If I am right and you are trying to scroll to specific other section the using scrollBy, or scrollTo, could be a good way to go.